# MapBox map space position into longlat Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I would like to know about what function or API that should I call when I want to get LongLat from object that I spawned above current display Map ?

To transform from LongLat to Unity location is using Abstract Map GeoToWorldPosition. Now, I want to reverse the number, from Unity location into LongLat.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method `WorldToGeoPosition(Vector3)` for the abstract map too

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't see this method earlier, think I missed it while scrolling also searching wrong word, I did search for WorldPositionToGeo instead of WorldToGeoPosition haha, thank you :D